# Unwanted BibTeX error warnings

Tags: bibtex

I have recently noticed that I get 3 BibTeX warnings on each compilation of my documents (BibTeX v0.99, pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021/W32TeX)).  I am not consciously using BibTeX, and nor do I want to, so why is this happening and how can I avoid it?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
Hello!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would help if you could give a `MWE` showing where the problem is. The code you give will not give a `BibTex`  warning since there is no bibliography.

Comment: as Denis says the code you show does not involve bibtex, perhaps you are using some script that always runs pdfatex and bibtex, just in case. The text you show is not an error or even a warning it is simply the bibtex startup banner that will show if bibtex is run. If you want more help you would need to say how you are running bibtex here.

Comment: Are you using texify to compile?

Comment: I am using WinEdt and TeXLive and it seems that the button that used to invoke PDFLaTeX was invoking PDFTeXify instead, so that explains it.   I have set it back to PDFLaTeX and all is well.  Thanks for the help.